# CSS: Why the right margin is larger than the left one (with the same unit)?

Tags: css, margin

I have (just parameters relative to positioning here):

```css
   .container{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .inner-container{
        margin: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="inner-container">
           Hello World!
       </div>
    </div>
```

I was expecting that the spaces, on the left and the right hand side, between the "***inner-container***" and the "***container***" are equals, but it isn't: the space on the right hand side is TWICE as big as the one on the left.

[image]

Why? I want to have the "***inner-container***" in the middle (like "*align: center*") of the "***container***".

I've tried

```
body{ margin: 0px } // proposed by @Uttam
```

or (by someone who deleted his/her comment)

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

but neither the solution is working for me! I've also tried "[reset CSS](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html)" or add "*position: relative*" to "***container***" and "*position: absolute*" to "***inner-container***", but I still have the same problem!

**Note:** thank you very much for your help (@Uttam and @Temani Afif). Your solutions should work, but it isn't for me. This is my whole code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
}

.container {
  width: 98%;
  margin: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: justify; 
}

.inner-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid #337ab7;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0.2rem 0.1rem; // trying to correct the problem
  box-shadow: 1px 1px gray; 
}
```

Comment: Hey @bern19 please try elaborating your question by adding some screenshots. Add screenshots of what bug are you struggling with and what you wanna achieve

Comment: do you want to align your text in center? I'm not able to relate your screenshot with any bug in code

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a screenshot of what things currently look like so we have a few more clues.

Comment: @Mordred I put a screenshot, but the image is not showing up. It seems that I'm not allowed to put image or up vote someone (not enough reputation or something)

Comment: @Uttam My text is aligned center. I don't want to put all of my CSS here (big project), just enough to show my problem. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

margin between `container` and `inner-container` are equal but if you will not remove the default margin of body then you might face some issue related with **margin or padding.**

```css
body{
margin:0px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-container{
    margin: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner-container">
       Welcome World!
   </div>
</div>
```